# Tensorflow op with two inputs, return one of the two and override gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a synthetic gradient scheme in Tensorflow.

I need to have an op which takes two inputs and return one of them (i.e. an identity with a dummy variable). Something like `f(a, b): return a`

I need this because then I want to override the gradient with a formula which depends on `b`

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("SynthGrad")
def _SynthGrad(op, grad):
dim1 = tf.shape(op.inputs[1])[1]
dim2 = tf.shape(op.inputs[0])[1]
B = tf.random_normal([dim1, dim2])
synth_grad = tf.matmul(op.inputs[1], B)
return synth_grad
```

Writing a Python function and using `tf.py_func` is going to be a mess. Plus, I'd like to have this code running also on GPU and with `py_func` that wouldn't be the case.

How can I achieve this? Is there a TF op that could I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code during model definition to override gradient.
`tf.Graph` has [`gradient_override_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#gradient_override_map) construct to achieve the same

```
g = tf.get_default_graph()
...model, definiton, input other op etc

# gradient overrring map construct with the function `f` in your case
with g.gradient_override_map({"op_name": "SynthGrad"}):
    f_out = f(op_in_1, op_in_2, name="op_name")

...
# code related to custom function and custom gradient from your question
def f(a, b, name='some_name'):
    ... some stuffs
    return a    

@tf.RegisterGradient("SynthGrad")
def _SynthGrad(op, grad):
    dim1 = tf.shape(op.inputs[1])[1]
    dim2 = tf.shape(op.inputs[0])[1]
    B = tf.random_normal([dim1, dim2])
    synth_grad = tf.matmul(op.inputs[1], B)
    return synth_grad
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to have the desired behavior in this way. What I'd like is to be able to express the forward operation using only TF ops, in this way the code will run on GPU when available.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you managed to solve your problem but the names 'op_name' and 'some_name' in above solution would not show on the graph. So you will not be able to use gradient_override_map({"op_name": "SynthGrad"}).

One possible solution:
If you have a custom tensorflow op x=f(a,b) in forwardpass but you want that to behave as g(a,b) in backwardpass, you can do something like this:

t=g(a,b)
out=t+tf.stop_gradient(f(a,b)-t)

However, you need to define g(a,b) in C++ as a dummy/identity operator with a name. Later, you can use gradient_override_map.

Comment: I solved the problem by implementing it in PyTorch :) thanks for the help anyway. I would love to see someone come up with a general implementation of Direct Feedback Alignment in Tensorflow, it probably requires a lot of advanced TF concepts and I would learn a lot from it